# How do I remove the blue line around the text in a JButton? - Java

Tags: java, jbutton

I have a `JButton` like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("ExampleText") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    {   
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 2));
    }
};
```

And it looks like this:

[image: ExampleImage]

And as you can see, there is kind of a blue border around the text. How can I remove it?

Comment: It will be there when the button is in focus.

Comment: @user3437460 But can't I avoid that?

Comment: Think carefully about whether you want to do this.  Displaying which component has focus in a GUI is a practice based on decades of human-computer interaction research.  In particular, users who use the keyboard (often because the mouse is not an option) will be hampered if you inhibit this.

Comment: @VGR Yes, but I want to change the backgroundcolor instead, if the button is in focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setFocusPainted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted-boolean-):

```
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

Comment: This can and should be done without subclassing JButton.  Just call the public methods after constructing a regular JButton.

Comment: @VGR ok. Just wanted to follow the example given. Rollback done.